# Content not displaying on web page via jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css

Is there an issue with my code?

When navigation button is clicked on the left sidebar, the content should be displayed on the right side.

Instead, both London and Paris details are displayed on the page. There is no effect when the navigation buttons are clicked. Is there an error in my syntax or logic?

```
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
    .header {
      background-color:black;
      color:white;
      text-align:center;
      padding:5px;
    }
    .nav {
      line-height:30px;
      background-color:#eeeeee;
      height:300px;
      width:100px;
      float:left;
      padding:5px;
    }
    .active {
      font-weight:bold;
    }
    .section {
      width:350px;
      float:left;
      padding:10px;
    }
    .footer {
      background-color:black;
      color:white;
      clear:both;
      text-align:center;
      padding:5px;
    }
    </style>

  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="header">
      <h1>City Gallery</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="nav">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#section-london">London</a></li>
        <li><a href="#section-paris">Paris</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="section-london" class="tab-content">
      <h2>London</h2>
      <p>London is the capital city of England. It is the most populous city in the United Kingdom, with a metropolitan area of over 13 million inhabitants.</p>
    </div>
    <div id="section-paris" class="tab-content">
      <h2>Paris</h2>
      <p>Paris, France's capital, is a major European city and a global center for art, fashion, gastronomy and culture. Its picturesque 19th-century cityscape is crisscrossed by wide boulevards and the River Seine. </p>
    </div>
    <div class="footer">Footer</div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
      $('.nav ul li:first').addClass('active');
      $('.tab-content:not(:first)').hide();
      $('.nav ul li a').click(function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var content = $(this).attr('href');
        $(this).parent().addClass('active');
        $(this).parent().siblings().removeClass('active');
        $(content).show();
        $(content).siblings('.tab-content').hide();
      });
    });
    </script>

  < /body>
</html>
```

Comment: $(content).siblings('.tab-content').hide(); is the issue. just hide .tab-content first then show $(content)

Answer (score 3):

You need include jQuery library in your code.
Add :

```
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
```